# Reference to a bash variable whose name contains dot

Tags: bash

I have a bash variable: `agent1.ip` with `192.168.100.137` as its value. When I refer to it in `echo` like this:

```
echo $agent1.ip
```

the result is:

```
.ip
```

How can I access the value?

**UPDATE:** my variables are:

[image]

Comment: How did you get the `.` in the variable name in the first place?

Comment: Indeed, as @TomFenech hints at that's not a valid variable name. It shouldn't be possible to *have* a variable with that name at all.

Comment: i'm using a tool that run my bash and it has env variable with dotted name...

Comment: Can you confirm you have that variable? It might be that your tool is not creating the variable you think it is.

Comment: yes, i confirm that the variable exists.

Comment: The table you have shown doesn't prove that the variable exists with that exact name. It is possible that you have an associative array (like `"${node['name']}"`), for example.

Comment: weird! You could instead try with perl perl -e 'print $ENV{"agent1.port"}'

Comment: `bash.ip=192.168.100.137` is a perfectly valid string to include in the environment. It's just not a string which `bash` can automatically turn into a variable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Bash itself doesn't understand variable names with dots in them, but that doesn't mean you can't have such a variable in your environment.  Here's an example of how to set it and get it all in one:

```
env 'agent1.ip=192.168.100.137' bash -c 'env | grep ^agent1\\.ip= | cut -d= -f2-'
```

Comment: Then you can assign that value to a valid bash variable name.

Comment: The grep regex is wrong, please quote the \ or it will also accept agent1_ip or agent1-ip, etc

Comment: @drizzt: you're right, I added another `\` to properly escape the pattern.

Answer (score 14):

Since `bash.ip` is not a valid identifier in `bash`, the environment string `bash.ip=192.168.100.37` is not used to create a shell variable on shell startup.

I would use `awk`, a standard tool, to extract the value from the environment.

```
bash_ip=$(awk 'BEGIN {print ENVIRON["bash.ip"]}')
```

Answer (score 9):

The cleanest solution is:

```
echo path.data | awk '{print ENVIRON[$1]}'
```

Answer (score 5):

Is your code nested, and using functions or scripts that use ksh?

Dotted variable names are an advanced feature in ksh93. A simple case is

```
$ a=1
$ a.b=123
$ echo ${a.b}
123
$ echo $a
1
```

If you first attempt to assign to `a.b`, you'll get

```
 -ksh: a.b=123: no parent
```

IHTH

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
export myval=`env | grep agent1.port | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`;echo $myval
```

Comment: Note that `.` in `grep` means "any character," so this will behave badly if there is e.g. `agent1Sport`.  Likewise `flagent1.port` or `blagent1Sportier`.  See my answer for a more exact expression.