# bash bad substitution in script

Tags: bash, groovy

I have some groovyscript. I execute a shell command:

```
sh "echo ${myParams.TEST}"
```

This prints:

```
works
```

Now I try to do the same but in a bash script in the shell:

```
sh'''#!/bin/bash
echo "${myParams.TEST}"
'''
```

But this gives always the same error: `bad substitution`

EDIT:

```
sh """#!/bin/bash
echo \"${myParams.TEST}\"
"""
```

This works: output is: `works`

Now I try:

```
sh """. ./script.sh"""
```

`script.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hey"
echo '\"${myParams.TEST}\"'
```

Output is again:

```
hey
bad substitution
```

Comment: You will want to see [Reference to a bash variable whose name contains dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506539/reference-to-a-bash-variable-whose-name-contains-dot)

Comment: Also, invoking with `"` or `'` allows bash to expand the variable value or not. If you are using `"` you may have to scape the `$` for the variable substitution.

Comment: If you are just trying to output a literal `echo ${myParams.TEST}`, then *single-quote*, e.g. `echo '${myParams.TEST}'` to prevent *variable expansion* or escape the `$`, e.g. `\$`.

Comment: How is this a Groovy script? It looks like pure bash.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I'm trying to call a bash script from inside groovy (jenkinsfile) using sh and I try to use a groovy variable in the bash script

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Ow can I make my script.sh work to print the content of ${myParams.TEST} like it works in the other examples above

Comment: Where do you get `sh` from?  This should be jenkins tagged, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sh """../script.sh"""
```

just starts shell script

and shell script don't know anything about your groovy variables

so, you have to pass values to your script like this:

```
sh """../script.sh \"${myParams.TEST}\" """
```

then you can access the value of `myParams.TEST` in bash  by `$1` as it is the first parameter for it

Comment: I do understand, but why is this working: `sh """#!/bin/bash
echo \"${myParams.TEST}\"`
""" isn't it also not just a shellscript?

Comment: it works because  groovy substitutes ${myParams.TEST} to real value before executing the shell

Comment: If `sh` behaves like Groovys `.execute()` on a string, i doubt those `\"` will be of any help here.