# How to prevent parameter expansion from happening in bash command-line?

Tags: linux, bash

What I want to accomplish:

```
payara@56a60a022850:~/bin$ ./asadmin create-jvm-options -Dlogback.configurationFile=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/lib/classes/logback.xml
```

this should result in an entry in my `domain.xml` as follows:

```
<jvm-options>-Dlogback.configurationFile=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/lib/classes/logback.xml</jvm-options>
```

but I get the error:

```
bash: -Dlogback.configurationFile=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/lib/classes/logback.xml: bad substitution
```

What is exactly wrong? I am inside a docker container.

Comment: hi Inian, as you mentioned, my exact problem was the dot.

Comment: as said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506539/reference-to-a-bash-variable-whose-name-contains-dot it works with create-jvm-options -Dlogback.configurationFile='${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/lib/classes/logback.xml'

Comment: Use single quotes to prevent parameter expansion.