# Why am I getting " No such file or directory" for a directory that exists?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm running a script called `setenv.sh` that sets the environment variables. One of the lines is:

```
config.dir=/Users/arianna/work/next/conf
```

After running it, I get an error message saying: `config.dir=/Users/arianna/work/next/conf: No such file or directory`

I'm confused because this directory exists. I can copy and paste and cd into it.

I'm befuddled here. What's wrong?

Comment: When you say "after running it", do you mean when you run it? Or do you mean later on when you do something else? If the former, how exactly are you running the script? If the latter, what are you doing that causes that error message to be displayed?

Comment: I mean, this is the result of running command `./setenv.sh`. 

The error mesage is the result of the above command.

Comment: Note that the error message indicates that "`config.dir=`" is being treated as part of the file path, and *that* doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `.` in your variable is what is causing problems; in bash it's used as an environment variable and/or only valid within certain shells which can recognize it as a regular variable. I would recommend using an underscore unless you absolutely need to use a dot.

```
config_dir=/Users/arianna/work/next/conf
```

If you want to use it as an environment variable or retrieve it then you could do:

```
config_dir=$( env 'config.dir=/Users/arianna/work/next/conf' \
              awk 'BEGIN {print ENVIRON["config.dir"]}' )

echo "$config_dir"
```

**Explanation**:

↳ [Reference to a bash variable whose name contains dot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26506539/499581)